# How to globally disable Adobe scripting security warnings?

Tags: security, scripting, adobe-reader

### Questions

- How can I permanently disable the scripting warning and allow scripting in Adobe Reader X?
- Is this a policy setting, a local setting, or impossible?

### Background / Problem

At our enterprise, we make use of Adobe Reader X (though the reason still escapes me).

One of our enterprise applications allows the viewing and markup of PDFs.

However, the Adobe scripting warning pops up for some of these PDFs, and because of the way the application displays it, the user cannot allow scripting, rendering some of the app's pdf markup operations useless.

**Note**: We are aware of the security risks this entails and have examined our environment and processes to determine that this is a reasonable course of action in this scenario.

### Goal

- Remove the warning when opening a PDF in select cases so that our application may use PDFs properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to play with settings under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\9.0\JSPrefs`

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the best path to go down so far.